# Data Factory - Getting last Saturday from a current date

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I find the date of the last Saturday from a current date in ADF (set as a variable) ?

For example in SQL I can run this query and it will return the last Saturday:

[image]

but I don't want to create a lookup activity to connect to the database and run that query. I want to define it as a variable.

Is it possible to create a variable that always returns the last Saturday?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below expression to get the last saturday always in set variable activity.

```
@FormatDateTime(addDays(subtractFromTime(utcnow(),dayOfWeek(utcnow()),'Day'),-1),'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

**Set variable:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]